# Rubymotion implementation of the previous/next buttons in the webview

Tags: objective-c, ruby, rubymotion

I'm new to iOS development and recently started out with rubymotion.

Im currently working on a "start page" kind of application that loads an in app html/css/js file in a webview. The "start page" then links to different sections/pages on (a to be released) responsive design version of http://hiof.no .

My current build of the app is based on the PaintHTML example:
https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/tree/master/PaintHTML

The feature I'm stuck on at the moment is previous/next page navigation to navigate back and forth in the webview history.

The idea of the navigation feature is to have previous/forward buttons positioned fixed on the bottom left side of the app similar to the Path app "new content" button.

Any ideas how I can implement access to the webview history with "native" rubymotion code?

Answer (score 2):

the UIWebView have to methods **UIWebView#goBack** and **UIWebView#goForward**,

create two button and set the action to **@webView.goBack** and **@webView.goForward**; and you can enable the button with the methods [UIWebView#canGoForward and UIWebView#canGoBack]

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)